# How to disable "do you want to view only the webpage content that was delivered securely" warning?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, https

My website has complete https and its using outer jquery resource which is http.

In IE 8, when I'm redirecting the site it giving me 
"do you want to view only the webpage content that was delivered securely" warning How to avoid this?

Is there any script available which solve this problem?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: it is a setting on Internet Options - Advance , once u uncheck "Warn if changing between secure and unsecure mode." u wont get the message.

Comment: Why not just serve your own copy of jQuery over HTTPS?

Comment: yes. but I m trying it to avoid this warning using some script instead of changes in browser setting? can we do this thing?

Comment: Feature requests like this are scary. If you can change a security setting for the end-user, so can anyone else, like EVIL PIRATES whose website you accidentally visited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We cannot bypass the security alert using any javascript or jquery, because it is concern to security.

Answer (score 7):

There seem to be two possible problem areas and your post doesn't make clear which is the issue:

- You are referencing a jquery script file hosted on another site which is not secure.

As JamWaffles said, you should simply host a copy of the jquery file on your own site so it can be accessed using https. See this answer for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1458356/773798

Or ...

- You are redirecting from a secure to an unsecure site.

I don't think this is what's causing the problem, because it will generate a different message, but for details on how to redirect from a secure to an unsecure page, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3784676/773798

Comment: Hi, 
Now I have added SSL for both applications. Assume "https:// www.a.com" and "https:// www.b.com". 
"https:// www.a.com" is accessing the wcf service from https:// www.b.com through $.ajax() call. I am also using jsonp to this functionality. 
When these application are not https it works fine. But the $.ajax() call fails when I make it https. 
It giving "Internel server error" in firebug on this $.ajax() call. 
Can we do such thing in secure mode?

Comment: Sorry for the slow response. I'm not familiar with JSONP, although it looks like the right approach to use for cross-domain calls. While I know from experience that jquery's $.ajax() calls work fine with https to the same domain, it looks like you'll either need to stick to JSONP's getJSON() method with url-based callbacks, or else use a proxy as described here: http://goo.gl/x4kLg

Answer (score 3):

Check and Change your Internet options In IE.

How ever u needed change like that.First Use Google it will be better.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/06/22/9797918.aspx

Hope this may helpful...

Answer (score 3):

it is a setting on Internet Options - Advance , once u uncheck "Warn if changing between secure and unsecure mode." u wont get the message.

Comment: yes. but I m trying it to avoid this warning using some script instead of changes in browser setting? can we do this thing?

Answer (score 3):

Please refer to link below.

[Solution to disable the https alert](https://kb.wisc.edu/wiscmail/page.php?id=17312)

Answer (score -1):

This *may not be useful* for you but to your **website users** will benefit from it:

Disabling **"Do you want to view only the webpage content that was delivered securely?"** in [IE 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_8)

[image: IE warning]

Follow the steps as shown:

Go to **Tools** -> **Internet options**

[image: Internet options]

Go to **Security tab** -> **Internet** -> **Custom level**

[image: Custom level]

In the Security settings pop up enable **Display mixed content**

[image: Display mixed content]

Repeat these steps for **Local intranet** and **Trusted sites** sections